# JMS COD not sending the response back

Tags: jms, spring-integration, ibm-mq

We are using IBM MQ and trying to receive a response from MQ manager (COD) when a request has been successfully consumed by the external application. I am not sure if I am setting the right parameters in the message header but I have tried various combinations and yet, no luck so far. I don't see the response coming back to the queue. Please find my configuration below and help me with correct configs.

This is first config

```
Message<String> msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(message.getPayload())
                                    .setHeader(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_REPORT_COA, "MQRO_COA_WITH_FULL_DATA")
                                    .setHeader(WMQConstants.JMS_REPLYTO, "QUEUEMANAGERNAME/QUEUENAME")
                                    .setHeader(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_REPLYTOQMGR, "QUEUEMANAGERNAME")
                                    .build();
                            jmsTemplate.get().convertAndSend(queue.get(), msg.getPayload());
```

This is other config -

```
Message<String> msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(message.getPayload())
                                    .setHeader(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_REPORT_COA, "MQRO_COA_WITH_FULL_DATA")
                                    .setHeader(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_REPLYTOQ, "QUEUENAME")
                                    .setHeader(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_REPLYTOQMGR, "QUEUEMANAGERNAME")
                                    .build();
                            jmsTemplate.get().convertAndSend(queue.get(), msg.getPayload());
```

But still no response is getting generated. Any recommendations are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at or asked the MQ admin to look at the queue manager error logs to see if there are any permissions errors.  You normally need specific permissions to allow for the COA to return.

Comment: You say COD in the text, but use COA in the code. Not going to be the problem, but you're not coding the correct report option. COA is only arrival on the queue, COD is delivery to the application. @JoshMc is right though, authority problems is likely to be the issue. The user ID in the message must be used, and it may not even be defined on the system doing the put.

Comment: I agree, It is COA as of now, I changed it as I didn't wanted to be dependent on Remote MQ manager as we don't know if it is down or any other issue. So I thought of getting COA worked and COD should follow same principal in terms of application code. I will get MQ config checked but do you think that application code is correct and which config out of the 2 highlighted above is correct?

Comment: @Vaibs - both COA and COD are generated by the remote queue manager. If the message has not been placed by the channel on the queue on the remote queue manager, then no COA will be generated. COA also requires +passid authority on the replyQ.